# How to make a java script statement apply only to a certain browser width

Tags: javascript

So basically I have my java script already set up, but what I'd like to do is have that js statement only be applied at a certain browser width. So in this case, I only want the statement to be applied at a max broswer width of 575px, kind of like a media query on css. Here's what I got:

```
<script>  $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos <= 0) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('top-of-page');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('top-of-page');
    }
});
   </script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the down votes guys! Feel free to let me know why too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) to find the width of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of what your code might look like if you wanted to run the above javascript statement applied to certain browser width (max of 575px)

```
<script>
    if (window.innerWidth <= 575){
        $(window).on("scroll", function(){
            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scrollPos <= 0) {
                $(".navbar-default").addClass("top-of-page");
            } else {
                $(".navbar-default").removeClass("top-of-page");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```